# How to read poorly formatted Open Graph urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-opengraph

I am currently using the following code in my `Product` model to read and save the `og:image`s of retail sites.

```
def photo_from_url(url)
  if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").blank?
    photo_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"]
    self.photo = URI.parse(photo_url)
    self.save
  end
end
```

While this works on most pages, there are some `og:image`s that return `bad URI(is not URI?)`
An example of such a link is the following link format at H&M's retail site.

```
http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2012/K71 05701 95313 06 0043 0.jpg],rotate[],width[],height[],x[],y[],type[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/facebook]
```

Obviously, this isn't a pretty link (even StackOverflow's Markdown parser can't tell that it's a link...), but it does actually work when pasted directly into a browser.

What can I do to correctly read a link like this?

Comment: _“What can I do to correctly read a link like this?”_ – apply proper URL encoding to the chars that are not allowed inside an URL …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoa, that looks like a nasty URL. Nice URL scheme notwithstanding, I suggest you simply escape your URLs using [`URI::Escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html):

```
irb(main):001:0> url = "http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2012/K71 05701 95313 06 0043 0.jpg],rotate[],width[],height[],x[],y[],type[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/facebook]"
=> "http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2012/K71 05701 95313 06 0043 0.jpg],rotate[],width[],height[],x[],y[],type[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/facebook]"
irb(main):002:0> uri = URI.escape url
=> "http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2012/K71%2005701%2095313%2006%200043%200.jpg],rotate[],width[],height[],x[],y[],type[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/facebook]"
irb(main):003:0> URI(uri)
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x000000024321d0 URL:http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2012/K71%2005701%2095313%2006%200043%200.jpg],rotate[],width[],height[],x[],y[],type[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/facebook]>
```

Comment: Thanks @jonallard. Does this mean all I need to do is escape the url for the og:image, as in `photo_uri = URI.escape(photo_url)`? This results in `undefined method `gsub' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x007fe59cb296a0>`. What might I be doing wrong? Thanks for handling such a noob question!

Comment: From the looks of it, you would be feeding a Nokogiri::XML::Attr in the `escape` method rather than a String (URI). I would check what exactly you're passing into that method.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I just added a `.to_s` to what I was passing into the escape method(ie. the output I get from Nokogiri), and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!